# Delete from a table where value doesn't exist in another table

Tags: mysql

I've got a table (`table_1`) I'm trying to delete out of, based on if a value doesn't exist in another (`table_2`)

`table_2` can have multiple entries based on the id from `table_1`, such as:

```
+----------+--------------+
|table_1_id|table_2_active|
+----------+--------------+
|1         |0             |
+----------+--------------+
|1         |1             |
+----------+--------------+
|2         |0             |
+----------+--------------+
```

To clarify, `table_2` links `table_1` and another table with other values, including whether or not that link is `active`, with a 0 for "inactive" and a 1 for "active".

I want to delete from `table_1` (and consequently from `table_2`) where there are no "active" entries in `table_2`.

Started out with this:

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM `table_1` t1
LEFT JOIN `table_2` t2 ON t1.id = t2.table_1_id
WHERE t2.active = 0
```

However this will delete things that have an "inactive" link, even if it still has an "active" one. For example, in the table above, I want to delete where `table_1_id` is 2, and not 1. I've also tried going into subqueries, but having issues getting the id from the main query to be used in the subquery, and I have to believe there's a way to do this without subqueries.

How do I delete from `table_1` and `table_2` where there are no `table_2`.`active` = 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invert the `active` test, and move it into the `ON` clause. Then check for a non-matching element in the `WHERE` clause.

```
DELETE t1 FROM `table_1` t1
LEFT JOIN `table_2` t2 ON t1.id = t2.table_1_id AND t2.active = 1
WHERE t2.table_1_id IS NULL
```

You only need to delete from `table_1` here, since the `LEFT JOIN` won't include any existing rows from `table_2`. If `table_1_id` is declared as a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, the related inactive rows in `table_2` will be deleted automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an old schema and there are no foreign keys. I'll give this a shot, thanks

Comment: Then do two queries. After this query, delete everything from `table_2` that isn't in `table_1`.